# IllegalArgumentException calling an EJB in a servlet

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb

I've an enterprise application with an EJB module and a WAR module. In the EJB module I've a singleton used for doing basic initilization/shutdown procedures (socket connections, etc):

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class ExecutionBean {
  @EJB
  private TServerLocal tServer;
  @PostConstruct
  private void atStartup() {
    this.startup();
  }
  @PreDestroy
  private void atShutdown() {
    this.shutdown();
  }
  public void startup() {
    [...]
  }
  public void shutdown() {
    [...]
  } 
}
```

In the WAR module I've a set of servlets I can use to shutdown, start and restart the app, simply calling the shutdown and startup methods of the ExecutionBean, like this:

```
public class shutdown extends HttpServlet {
  @EJB
  private ExecutionBean execBean;

  protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
      out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
      out.println("<html>");
      out.println("<head>");
      out.println("<title>Servlet shutdown</title>");      
      out.println("</head>");
      out.println("<body>");
      execBean.shutdown();
      out.println("shutdown done");
      out.println("</body>");
      out.println("</html>");
    }
  }
  [...]
}
```

Sometimes, after some deployment cycles (with hot-deployment or undeploy and deploy, it doesn't matter) glassfish starts to mark my servlets as unavailable with this kind of error:

```
[2016-02-16T02:29:30.201-0300] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=22 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1455600570201] [levelValue: 900] [[
  StandardWrapperValve[shutdown]: Allocate exception for servlet shutdown
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set com.tecytal.tyterisk.ExecutionBean field com.tecytal.tyterisk.servlets.shutdown.execBean to com.tecytal.tyterisk.servlets.shutdown
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:75)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:764)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl._inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:665)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.inject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:484)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.injectInstance(InjectionManagerImpl.java:141)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.injectInstance(InjectionManagerImpl.java:127)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl.createManagedObject(InjectionManagerImpl.java:324)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.createServletInstance(WebContainer.java:983)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.createServletInstance(WebModule.java:2130)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1404)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:1211)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:237)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

If I restart glassfish, everithing works fine. 
This error make no sense to me, execBean is not a field and I'm not trying to set nothing, only call a method. Am I doing something illegal so after some execution glassfish goes mad calling reflect.Field.set, or it's a know bug? Is there something "strange" in my code justifying this behavior?
I've searched in forums, etc, but I've found nothing.

Comment: It is telling you that the "injection" did not work for some reason. "execBean" is indeed a field in your servlet, it tries to inject the EJB into it and fails. I guess it is some classloading issue, but I don't have a solution unfortunately.

Comment: Ok, so the problem is the underlying injecton. Any idea why it works perfectly and suddenly stops without any apparent reason?